# Is there a particular Turing Machine which halting is undecidable in all formal systems?

Tags: set-theory, computability, turing-machines, tiling

Hanf and Myers showed in 1974 that there exists a *single* set of tiles that will tile the plane only in a *non-computable* way. How are we to interpret this? Does it imply that there is a particular Turing Machine which halting is undecidable in *whatever* formal system?

I know that non-computability is a feature of a family of problems, not a single problem. So I am not sure if I understood this correctly.

Edit: This is the link to the article by Hanf (1974) where he proves that there exists a single set of tiles tiling the plane in a non-recursive way: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2272640 (the article is only 2 pages long)

Is this an example of a single problem to which no algorithm can decide? Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: Yes: the universal machine.

Comment: Why would the Universal Turing Machine's halting be non-computable?

Comment: I think @MarkSaving is talking about the "full halting behavior" - that is, the set of *all* inputs on which a universal machine halts. By contrast, usually when we don't specify an input we're talking about what happens if we give the machine in question its own code as input, so that's a single-bit question whose ease of answering will vary depending on the particular universal machine used.

Comment: Thanks @NoahSchweber! And do you have any thoughts on the _single_ set of tiles that tiles the plane only in a non-recursive way? Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hanf and Myers showed in 1974 that there exists a single set of tiles that will tile the plane only in a non-computable way. How are we to interpret this? Does it imply that there is a particular Turing Machine which halting is undecidable in whatever formal system?

There is a crucial **type difference** here: we have to distinguish between problems with a single-bit (or natural number) answer, and problems with a more complicated (= "morally equivalent" to a real number or set of integers) answer. In fact, we should *also* allow problems with multiple solutions - so-called "mass problems."

Given a tileset $T$, there are two natural questions we can ask about it:

- "Does $T$ tile?" This question has exactly one correct answer, and that answer is a single bit.
- "*How can* $T$ tile?" (assuming that $T$ can in fact tile the plane). This question may have many correct answers (= valid tiling methods), but each individual answer is a highly structured object: at first glance, it may take infinitely many bits of information to fully describe a tiling of the plane.

The Hanf/Meyers result addresses the second type of question. Meanwhile, questions of the first sort can never be undecidable in all formal systems, because we can always add the correct solution as a single axiom to our favorite formal system (whereas the whole point of Hanf/Meyers is that no correct solution is simple enough to be so added).

Comment: Makes sense! So _there is_ one algorithm that can decide whether or not the tileset T that Hanf/Myers constructed tiles the plane or not (which in this case it does), despite the fact that the _way_ T tiles the plane is non-computable.

Comment: @CharbelBejjani On that note, keep in mind that yes/no questions are only computationally interesting when we ask infinitely many of them at once (e.g. ask for a decision procedure for telling whether a tileset *of a certain form* tiles the plane). Otherwise, one of the two machines "Always output 'yes'" and "Always output 'no'" (or a finite variant of same) will do the job.